# How to detect the default GPU at Runtime?

Tags: c++, opengl, interop, opencl, gpu

I have a little weird problem here that i´m having a lot of dificulties to find out the answer.

I have a C++ 3D Engine, and I´m using OpenCL for optimizations and OpenGL interoperability.

In My machine i have Two GPU´s installed, a GTX 960 and a AMD R9 280X.

Everything is working fine, including the detection of the GPU´s and CPU and
the graphics interoperability are running really fast as expected.

But, allways in a machine we have a default GPU on the system(This are setup on windows depending the order we install the drivers).

So, when i´m starting read all the devices and detect the GPU´s when i try create the interoperability contexts i have a weird situation:

When i have AMD as default GPU:
in the case of NVIDIA devices the OpenCL returns to me an error informing that its not possible create the CL context(Becouse is not the default GPU), and when i create the OpenGL context for the AMD GPU the context are created properly.

When i have NVIDIA as default GPU:
in the case of NVIDIA devices the context are created properly , but when i try create the AMD context, instead return me an error, the system Crash!

So, my main problem is how to detect the default GPU during Runtime to create interoperability contexts, only for the default GPU since the AMD are crashing instead return error...(Becouse with the errors i can setup a flag informing the default GPU based on this results...).

Anyone have an idea of how can i detect the default GPU at runtime using C++ ?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

One technique is to ask OpenGL for the device name and use that to choose the OpenCL device. Note: You may with to reduce these to enumerations before comparing, because the strings won't match (e.g. AMD vs. ATI).

Comment: I Like it, i will try find out how to do that.

Comment: `glGetString(GL_VENDOR)` -- map "AMD", "ATI", and "Advanced Micro Devices" all to your AMD enum, "NVIDIA" to NVIDIA enum, and "Intel" and "INTEL" to Intel enum. Then `clGetDeviceInfo` with `CL_DEVICE_VENDOR` and do similar mapping. Then compare enums.

Comment: Thanks so Much!
Works really well!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are mixing stuff from both GPUs. For example context is created for non-default GPU using device from default GPU. You can run into this sort of problems when using Khronos C++ bindings for OpenCL. Whatever is not created explicitly and set as default for non default GPU it will be created by the wrapper for you using default GPU.

Other C++ wrappers may suffer from similar problems. It's hard to say something more without seeing the source code.

Comment: Yes, i´m coding my own optimization component from scratch , and i mixing many contexts since i have more than one device.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a lot of tests, its working as expected and really Fast!!!

Basically i have two components:

01) OpenGL Component

02) OpenCL Component

So, in the OpenGL component i extract the GPU vendor from the graphics context created (Since the GL context is the first things created on the system to make possible render the graphics in a Window).

After This Initialization, i start the inicialization of the OpenCL component passing to it, the Vendor collected by OpenGL, since is the default GPU card registered on the system.

During the devices initialization i put a flag marking the default GPU for OpenGL interoperation, so for all other devices a normal execution context are created , and for the default GPU device the interoperation context are created.

after that when i request a kernel execution , i pass to it the component name using it, and if this component are a normal component the CPU and Second GPU devices for Heterogeneous computing are used, and if this call comes from the 3D component the GPU for OpenGL interoperation are used!!!

Reeaaallly Cool!!!

I tested inverting the Default GPU from NVIDIA to AMD and AMD to NVIDIA , and works lovelly!!!

I tested pointing my Math and Physics component to the second GPU and the 3D Graphics Component to the default GPU , and i reach great results!

The software are running like a Monster Dragster now!!!

Thanks so much for your help!

Kind Regards.